# Induced Current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current

[image]

How does opening the switch create induced current in X coil? Shouldn't there be no reaction since there's no current flowing if the switch is off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the switch is closed, then we have a current in the circuit and the corresponding vector potential $\vec {A}(x,y,z)$. When the switch is open, then with $t\rightarrow \infty$, the state $\vec {A}=0$ is set. Therefore, the vector potential depends on time after opening the switch, $\vec {A}=\vec {A}(t,x,y,z)$, induction $\vec {B}=\nabla \times \vec {A}$ also depends on time, therefore, an electric field is generated in the second circuit. We use the equation for the vector potential:
$$\frac {1}{c^2}\frac {\partial ^2\vec {A}}{\partial t^2}-\nabla^2\vec{A}=\mu_0 \vec{j}$$
If in the first circuit $\vec {j}=\vec {j0}$ for $t<0$ and $\vec {j}=0$ for $t>0$, then we have the initial data for this equation 
$$\vec {A}(0,x,y,z)=\vec {A}_0(x,y,z)$$ 
where $\vec{A}_0$ satisfies the equations
$$-\nabla^2\vec{A}_0=\mu_0 \vec{j}_0, \nabla .\vec {A}_0=0 $$
This allows us to calculate the electric field in the second circuit:
$$\vec {E}=-\frac {\partial \vec {A}}{\partial t}$$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I just touched physics so I’m not quite sure what those all means.

Comment: This means that the electromagnetic field cannot disappear after turning off the current in the first circuit, because an electromagnetic wave is generated that excites the current in the second circuit.

Comment: Ahhh I see thank you so much for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

For any change in the system, induced emf in either coil will try to maintain its existing flux. If the switch is opened, you will see a voltage spike in both coils and probably arcing on the switch.